# Is there a way to list who viewed a file (and when)?

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm searching for a little while and I can't find what I'm looking for, so it may be a good idea to ask it here.

Is there a way to obtain, by API, for a specific file, the name of the last user (and timestamp) who accessed a file?

Goal: to write to script to know who access what on my drive.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, what you want cannot be achieved. The `Drive Activity API` is used only for retrieving the activity on the specified file. You can gather the users who have **view access** but not the ones who have actually viewed the file.

The `action` object from the `Drive Activity API` is represented by the `action detail`. For a document at the moment, the `action details` are the following: `create`, `edit`, `move`, `rename`, `delete`, `restore`, `permissionChange`, `comment`, `dlpChange`, `reference`, `settingsChange`. Therefore, taking these into account as well, **you cannot see who viewed a file.**

Since the option of seeing the actual viewers of a file is still a relatively new feature in the UI, the option for the API does not yet exist.

What you can do instead is to file a **feature request** on Issue Tracker by accessing this link [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191587&template=823903).

**Reference**

- [Drive Activity API](https://developers.google.com/drive/activity/v2/reference/rest)

Comment: I requested the feature :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Drive Activity API](https://developers.google.com/drive/activity).